# Cannot find adb command even though it exists in path

Tags: android, zsh

Please help. Cannot find adb command even though it exists in path and it is there. It use to work but now has all of a sudden stopped working. Below is terminal output.

```
➜  ~ echo $PATH               
    /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin:/Users/lance/pear/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin:/Users/lance/pear/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:~/.composer/vendor/bin:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator

➜  ~ cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

➜  platform-tools ls
NOTICE.txt        dmtracedump       fastboot          make_f2fs         package.xml       sqlite3
adb               e2fsdroid         hprof-conv        mke2fs            sload_f2fs        systrace
api               etc1tool          lib               mke2fs.conf       source.properties

➜  platform-tools ~

➜  ~ adb devices
zsh: command not found: adb

➜  ~
```

Comment: What are the permissions for `adb`? You could also make an `alias` for your shell to `adb`.

Comment: Thanks but it seems react-native is having issues running adb commands so i think I need it to be in my path and an alias will not help. Permissions are -rwxrwxrwx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh` (unlike `bash`) does not substitute `~` checking `PATH`. It also does not expand `~` within any quotes, including double quotes.

So when adding to `PATH` you have to either

- use `~` in an unquoted string
- use the full path without `~` (with any necessary quotes),
- use `$HOME` instead of `~` (within double quotes or unquoted) or

For example:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:/Users/lance/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:'/Users/lance/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools'
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
```